# Point esp to array of characters

Tags: string, assembly, x86, stack, calling-convention

I am attempting to pass a string to a procedure via pushing the string onto the stack. I am aware that command line arguments are similarly pushed onto the stack so in an attempt to understand them, I figured making a contrived prototype that pushes a contiguous array of ASCI characters onto the stack, and accesses the string via a called procedure. However when running the code I am only able to access a single character rather than the array via `printf` format string `%c`. When using the format string specifier `%s` I receive a segmentation fault. Perhaps I am misunderstanding how memory addressing works and how to correctly access data the `esp` is pointing to. Here is my attempt:

```
; assemble and link with:
; nasm -f elf test.asm && gcc -m32 -o test test.o

section .text
global  main
extern printf

some_proc:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]

    push eax
    push format_str
    call printf

    mov esp, ebp ; Deallocate local variables
    pop ebp ; Restore the caller’s base pointer value

    ret 4

main:
    push 0x00796568 ; hey\0
    call some_proc

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

section  .data
    format_str     db `%s\n\0`      ; <- doesn't work
    ;format_str     db `%c\n\0`  <- works
```

This code only outputs the first 'h' character and not the entire contiguous array of strings `hey`. What modifications do I need to make to this code to perform the correct logic/output?

Expected stdout:

```
hey
```

Actual stdout:

```
Segmentation Fault
```

If you see any bugs in my code please notify me, I am new to assembly.

Comment: The `%s` directive expects the address of a string to be pushed on the stack, not the string itself.  Fix your code by changing `mov eax, [ebp+8]` to `lea eax, [ebp+8]` to push the address of the string instead.  Note that usually you would pass strings to functions by passing their addresses, not by pushing them on the stack.

Comment: You normally wouldn't point ESP itself at an array, unless you're abusing `pop` to read through an array with better performance than `lodsd` or something, like in [Extreme Fibonacci](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618) (code golf optimized for size *and* somewhat for speed).  But that wouldn't normally make sense for bytes.